# Block access for all the users in Apache Ranger

Tags: apache-ranger

I think Apache Ranger does not support blocking all the users in a Policy using '*' simply.

Does Apache Ranger API provide any way to do this?

I can think of a way to first get all users using

```
curl -u <Username>:<Password> -X GET /service/xusers/users | jq '.vXUsers[].name'
```

And then put them in the below API to block all users

```
POST /service/public/v2/api/policy
```

Is there any way we can just use '*' on UI under Select User tab?

Answer (score 0):

> I think Apache Ranger does not support blocking all the users in a Policy using '*' simply.

You do not need to block the users all together, just create a policy and do not specify any access permissions for any users. Unless you specify the permissions explicitly, by default, all the users will be denied.

For example, if a policy has no allow conditions as below;

[image]

Then, you will get denied for all actions;

```
0: jdbc:hive2://node5.cluster.com:10000/> create table t (id int);
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: HiveAccessControlException Permission denied: user [mapr] does not have [CREATE] privilege on [default/t] (state=42000,code=40000)
0: jdbc:hive2://node5.cluster.com:10000/>
```

When I specify an allow condition for a user to create a table as below;

[image]

Then, I can create a table;

```
0: jdbc:hive2://node5.cluster.com:10000/> create table t (id int);
INFO  : OK
INFO  : Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
No rows affected (0.687 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://node5.cluster.com:10000/>
```

Comment: You can also add {USERS} builtin variable in users tab which includes all the registered users.